# Type 'Void' has no member in function with enum Result<T>

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I have this code:

```
enum ApiConstans {
    static let BaseUrl = "http://myname.pl"
    static let iosPath = "/pub/ios/"
    static let jsonPath = "json.php"

    static var fullPath: String { return BaseUrl + iosPath + jsonPath }
}


struct Connect {
    enum Result<T> {
        case succes(T)
        case error(String)
    }

    func getJsonFromServer(parameters: String) -> Result<String> {

        let fullUrlString = ApiConstans.fullPath + parameters
        guard let url = URL(string: fullUrlString) else {
            return .error("Error 100: Problem with url")
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return .error("Error 100: Problem with url")
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .error("Error 101: Problem with url")
            }

            debugPrint("R> \(fullUrlString)")
            return .succes(data)
        }
    }

    func checkUsersLogin(login: String?, password: String?) ->  Result<String> {
        getJsonFromServer(parameters: "?action=LOGOWANIE&login=\(login!)&password=\(password!)")
    }

}
```

I have problem with errors in all return: Type 'Void' has no member 'error' and Type 'Void' has no member 'succes'

could I ask you to repair this code?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function?s=3|62.0655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use closure to return data when receive data from server.

```
typealias completionHandler = (Result<Data >) -> ()

func getJsonFromServer(parameters: String, completion: @escaping completionHandler) {
    let fullUrlString = ApiConstans.fullPath + parameters
    guard let url = URL(string: fullUrlString) else {
        return completion(.error("Error 100: Problem with url"))
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return completion(.error("Error 100: Problem with url"))
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return completion(.error("Error 101: Problem with url"))
        }

        debugPrint("R> \(fullUrlString)")
        return completion(.succes(data))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you that you return your `Result` from the async `dataTask` handler which is not expected to return your custom type.

The main issue of your code is that you perform an async operation (calling the server) in a sync way (immediately returning the result). Instead you should pass a callback closure to `getJsonFromServer` which you invoke in the `dataTask` handler.

Answer (score 0):

In case of block, the default return type is `Void` and hence that return is referencing to block return type. You need to use completion handler way to make it work.

```
enum ApiConstans {
    static let BaseUrl = "http://myname.pl"
    static let iosPath = "/pub/ios/"
    static let jsonPath = "json.php"

    static var fullPath: String { return BaseUrl + iosPath + jsonPath }
}


struct Connect {
    enum Result<T> {
        case succes(T)
        case error(String)
    }

    func getJsonFromServer(parameters: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String>) -> Void) {

        let fullUrlString = ApiConstans.fullPath + parameters
        guard let url = URL(string: fullUrlString) else {
            completion(Result.error("Error 100: Problem with url"))
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(Result.error("Error 100: Problem with url"))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                completion(Result.error("Error 100: Problem with url"))
                return
            }

            print("R> \(fullUrlString)")
            completion(Result.succes("CONVERT DATA TO STRING USE DATA HERE "))
        }
    }

    func checkUsersLogin(login: String?, password: String?, completion: @escaping (Result<String>) -> Void) {
        self.getJsonFromServer(parameters: "?action=LOGOWANIE&login=\(login!)&password=\(password!)", completion: completion)
    }

}
```

You can pass completion, also you have to wait for API to complete, So i suggest use handler technique for proper flow.